# Как выполнить сравнение символов двух строк в php

Tags: php, сравнение

Доброго времени суток.

Как в PHP выполнить определение наличия идентичных символов вне зависимости от их порядка например: "ab#cd" и "cdab#" = true

Comment: отсортируйте строки и сравните

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, разбить строки на массивы, отсортировать и сравнить их:

```
<?php

// преобразуем строки в массив
$array1 = str_split('ab#cd');
$array2 = str_split('cdab#');

// сортируем массивы
sort($array1);
sort($array2);

if ($array1 === $array2) {
    echo 'Строки одинаковы!';
}
```

Comment: то что нужно, спасибо за помощь.